# Error PLS-00382 (283: 17): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When adding package_status to the get_all_del_sku_sum procedure I get the following error: [Error] PLS-00382 (283: 17): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type. What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure get_all_del_sku_sum(
            p_str               in   number,
            p_to_date           in   date,
            p_cursor            out sku_qty_sum_ref)  is

        v_cursor            sku_qty_sum_ref;
        v_from_date         date;
        v_request_key        varchar2(100);

        begin

            v_from_date := trunc(p_to_date - 30);
            v_request_key:= p_str || '_' || p_to_date || '_' || current_timestamp;

             if (getTempTableRecCnt(v_request_key) = 0) then
                build_sku_qty_temp(p_str,v_from_date,p_to_date,v_request_key);
           end if;

            open v_cursor for
                select dept_id,dept_name,prdc_code,prdc_desc,brand_id,brand_name,sku_style,str_no,sku_no,package_status,color_code,color_name,null,sum(sku_qty)
                    from shp_trk_temp_wrk
                    where request_key = v_request_key
                    group by dept_id,dept_name,prdc_code,prdc_desc,brand_id,brand_name,sku_style,str_no,sku_no,package_status,color_code,color_name
                    order by dept_id,sku_no;

            p_cursor := v_cursor;

        end  get_all_del_sku_sum;
```

Comment: Have you made an equivalent update to your `sku_qty_sum_ref` type?

Comment: @EdmCoff Not sure what you mean? sku_qty_sum_ref seems to just be an OUT value. Its not anywhere else in the package

Comment: That's not a built-in type, so someone has created it to match the row you are returning. You could look at it by selecting it from `all_types` (or in SQL Developer looking under the "Types" folder). You won't be able to change the columns put into that type without changing the type definition.

Comment: @EdmCoff would I do desc all_types? What is the best way to view the "Types" folder?

Comment: @EdmCoff Okay, I found it in Toad for Oracle -> Database -> Schema Browser -> Types

Comment: There is no need for v_cursor. Just `open p_cursor for ...`

Comment: Can you replace sku_qty_sum_ref as sys_refcursor?